# Get value from JSON - node has space

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "obj": {
        "node1": {
            "child1": "value1"
        },
        "node , 2": {
            "child2": "value2"
        }
    }
}
```

Above is a fragment of my code (JSON). When I want to get "value1" I write "obj.node1.child1". But when I want to get "value2" I should write "obj.node , 2.child2", however this form is incorrect. Problem is with white sign -> space.

Comment: Use brackets notation - `obj['node , 2'].child2`.

Comment: FWIW, your question/problem has nothing to do with JSON. It's irrelevant where the JavaScript array/object came from.

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets to access the object property by passing the identifier as string instead:

```js
var data = {
  "obj": {
    "node1": {
      "child1": "value1"
    },
    "node , 2": {
      "child2": "value2"
    }
  }
}

console.log(data.obj['node , 2'].child2); // "value2"
```